# Unable to assign data after search filter completes in react native typescript for custom object

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, searchbar, flatlist

I have a custom object an array and storing api response in it and showing that data into UI for flatlist.

```
export type userInfo = {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  email: string,
  userAccount: number
};

export type userData = {
  page: number,
  pageSize: number,
  userInformation: userInfo[]
}

export const User: FunctionComponent = () => {

       const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
      const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<userInfo>();
  
      const [arrayholder, setArrayholder] =useState<userInfo>();

      useEffect(() => {
          setUserInfo(someState.userInfo);
          setArrayholder(someState.userInfo);
      }, [someState]);

searchData= (text: any)=>  {
            const newData = arrayholder?.userData.filter(item => {
                const itemData = item.title.toUpperCase();
                const textData = text.toUpperCase();
                return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
              });
              console.log("newData is", newData) //here throwing error
              setUserInfo(newData)
                setSearch(text)    
              }

}

          return (

//here showing searchbar
//here showing flatlist showing with userInfo

)
```

While trying to set newdata for userInfo, It is showing below error and unable to show search data in flatlist.

```
  Type 'userInfo[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: userInfo | undefined): userData | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

Any suggestions?

I am new to **typescript** language.

Comment: You set the userInfo state as userInfo type, but newData is an array. If you want the type of userInfo state to be an array (you probably want it to be an array since you're passing it to flatlist), replace `const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<userInfo>();` with `const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<userInfo[]>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` return an array:

```
arrayholder?.activities.filter
```

That‘s why userInfo requires an array type parameter.

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<userInfo[]>();
```

Comment: But flatlist data showing like this from main array                   <FlatList
                      data={userInfo?. userInfo}

Comment: Initialize with empty array ```const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<userInfo[]>([]);```

And pass userInfo to flatlist

```<FlatList data={userInfo}```